# Add Xhtml and Css verification buttons

Tags: w3c

i am developing a website and i got a requirement for adding the Xhtml and Css verification buttons from W3C site.i am trying from last 3 days but didn't got any solution that how to add it.can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is on the [w3c website](http://validator.w3.org/docs/help.html#icon).  Add this to your page:

```
<p>
  <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check/referer"><img
      src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10"
      alt="Valid XHTML 1.0!" height="31" width="88" /></a>
</p>
```

There is a similar block for the CSS validator.  You should probably make sure your page actually *is* valid XHTML or CSS, of course.

Comment: But be sure the page *does* validate first!

Comment: mean i only past that code in my website where i need it?if a user click on it then it will redirect to that page?

Comment: Yes, but like T.J. said, make sure your site validates first. If you just have the logo, but your site doesn't validate, then it's useless.

Answer (score 2):

After you [validate your XHTML](http://validator.w3.org/) (and pass validation, of course), you'll be given the markup to include the "valid" icons. You can do the [same thing for you CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/), too.

Answer (score 0):

For CSS Validator you can use the following site

```
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator/
```

To validate a site you can set the link of the button to

```
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=sitename&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&lang=en
```

where you set the site name in the `uri` query string parameter.

For XHTML you can use the following link

```
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=sitename&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Once your site passes, you'll see the buttons. You can see what the button code looks like here http://validator.w3.org/ and using the url www.w3c.org